# AngularFire - Remove Single row

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building an app with Firebase and AngularJS and I have a table with my users. From one of my view I want to create a form permit to delete users from the Firebase table . So I have a drop down menu with my users names and submit button

`var account = Fire base.get('follows','userId', $localStorage.accountId);
 account.$remove(account)`

these code i m using for delete single row. but can't to solve.

Comment: you are trying to cut the branch you are sitting on !! account.$remove(ACCOUNT) !!

Comment: try using  account.$remove();

Comment: i try all of..@Alok